# Square-summable sequence and Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Every square-summable sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$ is represented by $a_{n}=\widehat{f}(4^n)$, where $\widehat{f}(i)$ is Fourier coefficient of continuous function $f$.

Where can I find proof of this theorem?

Comment: There is a sequence that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \infty$ and we look for a function like above.